# How to get correct X and Y co-ordinates to pass with setDragImage.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I have a task to position element on its drop location. This positioning must be accurate. Meanwhile if I use setDragImage to set ghost image while dragging I am not able to put the mouse onto correct position as per the ghost image. Mozila supports addElement which doesn't need to pass any X and Y co-ordinates and thus it works perfectly. I want something similar in other browsers too.

My Code is ....

```
if (ev.dataTransfer.addElement) {
            ev.dataTransfer.addElement(dragStartImg.get(0));
    } else {
        ev.dataTransfer.setDragImage(dragStartImg.get(0), parseInt($(ev.target).css('left')) + ev.layerX, parseInt($(ev.target).css('top')) + ev.layerY);
    }
```

Please suggest me what to pass for X and Y option in setDrag Image such that its exact.

I am using HTML5 drag and drop along with javascript

Comment: why don't you use jquery-ui drag and drop functionality ?

Comment: I have to do it using html5 as it was part of the requirment

Comment: setDragImage uses 3 input, DOM Element, X position and Y Position. I want method to calculate this X and Y position so that user don't see any difference to its mouse pointer position.

Answer (score 1):

I had to use the same thing in one of my projects. I ketch  the event when I release(drop) the element and hide it. in place I out a new element in the correct position

```
    $('.droppable').droppable({
        accept: ".whatever",
        hoverClass: "highlight",
        activeClass: "ui-state-highlight",
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            //here you can replace the element with a new one in the correct position
        }
    });
```

Hope this helps.